# How to navigate between different routes without making the screen show leftovers from the previous route in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

I am using a `Navigator` widget to navigate between all the different routes that I have inside my app. This works quite well but the problem I am facing is that when navigating to the new page, there's a slight amount of time where the screen shows some leftover contents from the previous screen on top of the new screen and this looks like a bad user experience.

Here's a [slow-mo GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3Ig4.gif)  explaining what I mean.

And here's the build method for the main page:

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: SkpAppBar(
        title: _title,
      ),
      body: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        clipBehavior: Clip.none,
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              if (_showNavigationRail(context)) AnimatedContainer(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200), width: expanded ? 200 : 56),
              Expanded(
                child: Navigator(
                  key: navigatorKey,
                  onGenerateRoute: generateRoute,
                  initialRoute: '/login',
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          if (_showNavigationRail(context))
            AnimatedContainer(
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
              width: expanded ? 200 : 56,
              child: Material(
                elevation: 20,
                color: SkpColors.lightGreyF7,
                child: SkpNavigationRail(
                  extended: expanded,
                  onExtendedToggled: () => setState(() => expanded = !expanded),
                  onDestionationSelected: (String newRoute) {
                    // we actually need the context below the nested Navigator here
                    if (ModalRoute.of(context).settings.name != newRoute) {
                      navigatorKey.currentState.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(newRoute, ModalRoute.withName('/'));
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
        ],
      ),
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      drawer: _showNavigationRail(context) ? null : SkpDrawer(),
    );
  }
```

Q1: How do I make the code navigate to the new page without showing anything from the previous screen?

Q2: I am not able to get the current route name when using `ModalRoute.of(context).settings.name`. Is there another way of getting the current route name when using a `Navigator` widget with a navigator key?